# Unwanted Navigation property appearing in entity framework

Tags: json, entity-framework, serialization

I am using Entity Framework to create a Model, I am pretty new to the Entity Framework so bear with me.

I want my database to always be the end all be all of what gets generated, so I dont wnat to make modifications to the model itself. I want to amke all modifications to the database and just hit "Update Model From Database." This has been working swimmingly! 
However If I have a one to one relationship between two tables, and I have a foreign key constraint set in the database, I get a navigation property in the child table that goes back to the parent table.

So if I want to access the parent from the child I can do child.parent.fieldName

That sounds great in theory but my issue arises when I need to serialize the object for JSON created by the entity Framework. I always get an error because it tries to serialize the parent object along with the child object. which usually has an invalid state at this point so.. A) it cant be serialized and B) I wouldn't want all that extra info anyway.

Am I misconfiguring the database in some way? is there a way to have the database specify that I only want Parent.Child Navigation properties in the model? and not Child.Parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I misconfiguring the database in some way? is there a way to have the database specify that I only want Parent.Child Navigation properties in the model? and not Child.Parent?

No. Database knows nothing about your intention to use some tool on top of it. If you don't want the navigation property you must change it in EDMX by deleting it but sometimes you want the property but you also want a serialization. In such case you must either modify strategy used to generate your classes (if you are not using T4 templates it will be quite hard) to use some special attributes dependent on used serialization API to mark some properties as not serialized.

The correct approach is not serializing entities but creating special data transfer objects filled from entities which will contain only properties/data you are going to serialize so you will not get into this problem.

Comment: Thanks this is the way I ended up doing it. I also found a nifty command JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }); to ignore null values which reduced the overhead quite a bit.